# how to change arrays from ABAB to AABB

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a **large** matrix with columns in this way`[A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3]`. How rearrange it to format of `[A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3]`. In this case, it is step between two A is  three, what if the step size is n?

```
x=np.array(
[[ 1.1, 2.1 , 3.1,  1.2,  2.2, 3.2],
 [ 4.1, 5.1,  6.1,  4.2,  5.2, 6.2]])

x[:,[0,3,1,4,2,5]] # is there a way to do it not manually?
```

desired output

```
array([[1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 3.2],
       [4.1, 4.2, 5.1, 5.2, 6.1, 6.2]])
```

Comment: Sort it? `np.sort(x)`  see: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html

Comment: Please add _numpy_ tag.

Comment: Your intention is not clear enough, and your example doesn't make it any clearer.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: `(np.arange(3)[:,None]+np.array([0,3])).ravel()` generates the indexing array; you can tweak the numbers for other mixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using slice and [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([
...     [ 1.1, 2.1 , 3.1,  1.2,  2.2, 3.2],
...     [ 4.1, 5.1,  6.1,  4.2,  5.2, 6.2],
... ])
>>> n = 3
>>> np.hstack(x[:,i::n] for i in range(n))
array([[ 1.1,  1.2,  2.1,  2.2,  3.1,  3.2],
       [ 4.1,  4.2,  5.1,  5.2,  6.1,  6.2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(
[[ 1.1, 2.1 , 3.1,  1.2,  2.2, 3.2],
 [ 4.1, 5.1,  6.1,  4.2,  5.2, 6.2]])
n=3
x[:,np.concatenate([np.arange(i,x.shape[1],n) for i in range(n)])]
```

which gives

```
array([[ 1.1,  1.2,  2.1,  2.2,  3.1,  3.2],
       [ 4.1,  4.2,  5.1,  5.2,  6.1,  6.2]])
```

In the above code, `n` is the step size. So in `[A1,B1,C1,A2,B2,C2,A3,B3,C3]` there are three 1's (and three 2's and so on), and thus `n=3`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape` + `transpose`

```
x.reshape(2, -1, 3).transpose(0, 2, 1).reshape(2, -1)

array([[ 1.1,  1.2,  2.1,  2.2,  3.1,  3.2],
       [ 4.1,  4.2,  5.1,  5.2,  6.1,  6.2]])
```